# Setting background color of grouped UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a grouped `UITableView`. I am trying to make a custom `UITableViewCell` background:

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        self.contentView.opaque = YES;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rowbg@2x"]];

        //Change Indicator
        CGRect rect;
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 50);
        changeImageIndicator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        [self.contentView addSubview: changeImageIndicator];

        //Symbol
        rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 20);
        symbolLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        symbolLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        symbolLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:22];
        symbolLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        symbolLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview: symbolLabel];

        //Company
        rect = CGRectMake(10, 30, 180, 20);
        companyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        companyLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        companyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        companyLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        companyLabel.minimumFontSize = 10.0; 
        companyLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        companyLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:118.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:118.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [self.contentView addSubview: companyLabel];

        //Price
        rect = CGRectMake(190, 10, 100, 20);
        priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        priceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        priceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
        priceLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        priceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview: priceLabel];

        //Change
        rect = CGRectMake(190, 30, 100, 20);
        changeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        changeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        changeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
        changeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        changeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        changeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        changeLabel.minimumFontSize = 10.0; //adjust to preference obviously

        [self.contentView addSubview: changeLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The background color bleeds past the rounded corners. See image: [image]

How can I make this not bleed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a rounded top, middle and button graphic image and set it to the background view of the cell depending on which row it is.

Answer (score 4):

This works for iOS 3.0 and later:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` ?

Comment: Still no luck with seperator style none

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when nothing else did. Set the background color in IB to the grouped Table view color (default). Then in code, set the color to clearColor. I also have the cells marked opaque=NO and clearsContextBeforeDrawing=NO, but those settings alone didn't change anything until I added the clearColor by code – Bdebeez

Comment: I'm try to do following above ,It's ok

Comment: I want the background color of the UITableView to be the striped color. So that will not work. I even tried it with a clear color, same results.

Comment: I don't know how can do it, but you can replace striped color as striped image

Answer (score 0):

self.contentView.superview.opaque = YES;
        self.contentView.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rowbg@2x"]];

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the backgroundColor of the backgroundView rather than the contentView?

Comment: This also has the same results

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell background color in the **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"Gradient.png"]];
```